# How to give a flexible height to a table view in auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to have a scene which has a vertical stack view on top and a table view below it. The scene will be as follows:

```
View
    Stack view
    Table view
```

I want the auto-layout to:

> Let the stack view consume as much vertical space it needs to. The
>   rest of the vertical space goes to the table view.

I use these layout constraints:

```
stackView.leading == superview.leading
stackView.trailing == superview.trailing
stackView.top == topLayoutGuide.bottom
tableView.top == stackView.bottom
tableView.leading == superview.leading
tableView.trailing == superview.trailing
tableView.bottom == bottomLayoutGuide.top
```

But auto-layout complains:

> - Table View: Need constraints for Y position or height.
> - Stack View: Need constraints for Y position or height.

To fix this, I tried increasing the vertical content compression resistance priority of the stack view:

```
Stack View Content Compression Resistance Priority:
    Horizontal: 750
    Vertical: 751

Table View Content Compression Resistance Priority:
    Horizontal: 750
    Vertical: 750
```

But no luck, auto-layout is giving the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: auto-layout is a tool used to set window frames ... you need to specify the height of either tableView or stackView in order for it to do so.  With your constraints you have two view of indeterminate height

Answer (score 1):

Yes you got it right. But I would like to point out that views with dynamic content (like stack view and table views) do not have valid intrinsic content size in the interface builder.

> So, it seems like since stack views do not have an intrinsic size, we
>   need to put some elements with an intrinsic size in stack views in
>   order for auto-layout to infer a size for the stack views and layout
>   the content unambiguously.

So instead of adding some views just to avoid the auto layout warning what we should use is **Intrinsic Size Placeholder** in interface builder.

[image]

Comment: Are there any downsides to this approach (such as possibly hiding a subtle layout bug)?

Comment: Yes! it may happen that we make a view have placeholder intrinsic size and at runtime it may not find them. But since we mark it as place holder we MUST provide them at runtime.

Comment: In above case it will only happen when the stack view has no sub view at runtime. But we have added the stack view to hold views. If we do not provide it views at runtime, its our own implementation problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It turns out that we need to put a concrete element to the stack view in order to fix it. For example:

```
View
    Stack view
        Label
    Table view
```

Fixes the problem, whereas:

```
View
    Stack view
        Label
        Stack view
    Table view
```

Breaks it again, whereas:

```
View
    Stack view
        Label
        Stack view
            Label
    Table view
```

Fixes it again, etc.

So, it seems like since stack views do not have an intrinsic size, we need to put some elements with an intrinsic size in stack views in order for auto-layout to infer a size for the stack views and layout the content unambiguously.